# Old-style to new-style join conversion

Tags: t-sql, join

Consider the following code:

```
select (some columns)
from efdan_setup a,crit_efdan_val b,efdan c
where a.dan *= c.code
and b.codef *= c.codef
and b.mhnmis *= c.mhnmis
and b.etmis *= c.etmis
and b.ebdmis *= c.ebdmis
and b.mhnet *= c.mhnet
and b.mhnet_plir *= c.mhnet_plir
```

I am not very familiar with old-style joins, and I've read enough to understand I should probably change this. I wonder which is the new style equivelant. My guess:

```
from 
    crit_efdan_val b
    left join efdan c on 
        b.codef = c.codef 
        and b.mhnmis = c.mhnmis 
        and b.etmis = c.etmis 
        and b.ebdmis = c.ebdmis 
        and b.mhnet = c.mhnet
        and b.mhnet_plir = c.mhnet_plir
    right join fdan_setup a on a.dan = c.code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there - but mixing left joins and right joins is almost as bad as mixing matter and anti-matter.
In fact, some people (including myself) would rather avoid right joins altogether and stick with left joins only.

Here's how I would write this:

```
from efdan_setup a
left join efdan c
    on a.dan = c.code
left crit_efdan_val b
    on b.codef = c.codef
    and b.mhnmis = c.mhnmis
    and b.etmis = c.etmis
    and b.ebdmis = c.ebdmis
    and b.mhnet = c.mhnet
    and b.mhnet_plir = c.mhnet_plir
```

Comment: Are you more of a Physics Geek or Science Fiction Geek?

Comment: +1 As a side note it's ok to mix inner joins with outer joins, but please put the left joins after the inner joins to let the code more readable

Comment: @JohnCappelletti actually a little of both. I originally thought about writing 
"almost as bad as mixing carbohydrates and protein" but matter and anti-matter seems more harmful, and I think that unless you're either a bookworm like myself or an old-enough tried-all-diets-out-there the reference would be less obvious.

Comment: I'm a physicist so no problems with your analogy there! Also, avoiding right joins is very friendly to me....so thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :-)